# Excel web part for Sharepoint not displaying text boxes

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, excel-2013

I'm exposing an Excel 2013 worksheet in a Sharepoint 2010 page, using a Web Part.

For some reason,

**Sharepoint doesn't show floating objects, like text boxes or shapes, that are in my Excel sheet.**

I've got several graphs and cells filled with text, which I've collected under a single Named Item that selects the entire relevant sheet area.

These display fine, but text boxes won't , whether they're on top of another chart or on blank cells.

I've also tried simply exposing the whole worksheet without using named items at all, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text boxes are a form of `OfficeArt` and these features are not supported with excel web services.

From [MSDN - Excel Services Supported and Unsupported Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff595319%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

> **Features that Previously Prevented Excel Files from Loading**
>
> In Office SharePoint Server 2007, Excel workbooks that contain unsupported features like VBA macros, form controls, and so on are not loaded in Excel Services.
>   In SharePoint Server 2010, to help users work with this limitation, Excel Services ignores certain unsupported features. In other words, rather than blocking the entire file from loading Excel Services loads the file but you do not see the features that Excel Services does not support.
>   Following are features that do not prevent Excel Services from loading a file:
>
> - Cell comments.
> - Formula references to external books.
> - Query tables (also known as external data ranges).
> - Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA).
> - Any OfficeArt technology. For example, Shapes, WordArt, SmartArt, organization chart, diagrams, signature lines, ink annotations, and so on.
>
> Note that these features continue to be unsupported. This means that they do not render, execute, or work in any way as they do on the client. Most of the features in the list do not render in Excel Services.

Answer (score 1):

This was a LONG time ago, but I wanted to share a "potential" solution that I used that worked well

I'm in Excel 2016, and Sharepoint 2013

I created the shape I wanted and got it exactly the way I wanted it.
I selected the Shape, right-click, Cut
Right-click Paste AS PICTURE

Save the file.
Refre

Comment: This is still just as valid as ever.  The lack of support in SharePoint for the OfficeArt objects was driving me nuts until I found this workaround.